# Select Case Oracle Missing Expression or Missing Keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use `CASE` expression with `SELECT` with Oracle SQL developer and whatever I try doing I get a mistake. With the statement here under I get missing expression. I have checked and I think all required keywords are there. I tried modifying the code in many ways and the only thing that happens is sometimes I get

> "missing keyword error".

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN A.PARENT_ID IS NULL THEN 'NOPROB'
                                    ELSE 'PROB'
      END AS 'PROBLEMS'
FROM A
```

Comment: Is the tables name A?

Comment: Either remove apostrophe around PROBLEMS or replace it with quote mark.

Comment: No, I changed it, because it is named after a person !

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals. Use double quotes for delimited identifiers.

Comment: *"missing keyword error"* isn't an Oracle error message. Probably you got *ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected*.

Comment: @jarlh Then I get Invalid Identifier ( ORA-00904:  invalid identifier)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes, that one, and a bunch of others without mentioning the from

Comment: I tried the query as above and I only got ORA-00923, nothing else.

Comment: Single quotes are for character values, not for identifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this answer

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN PARENT_ID IS NULL THEN 'NOPROB'
                                    ELSE 'PROB'
      END AS PROBLEMS
FROM A
```

Comment: `select` list items don't need to be enclosed in brackets.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it doesn't help... ORA-00904:  invalid identifier - 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: So, is there a `PARENT_ID` column in table `A`? We know only what you tell us (and now it turns out that it wasn't entirely true).

Answer (score 0):

When giving an alias to a table name double quote is used not single qoute

```
SELECT 
     CASE WHEN A.PARENT_ID IS NULL THEN 'NOPROB'
                                   ELSE 'PROB'
     END AS "PROBLEMS"
FROM A
```

Comment: Only if the identifier you want to use is a reserved word or otherwise non-standard. Since it is generally a bad idea to use reserved words or non-standard identifier names, double quoting is generally best avoided.